A reference for a proof regarding the connected sum of two surfaces
I need a reference for the proof that any two connected sums of two nonempty, compact, connected 2-manifolds are homeomorphic. I am looking for a proof with the same construction as exercise 10-8 of the book "introduction to topological manifolds" by John M. Lee (exercise 10-8). I have searched in many algebraic topology books but cannot find the entire proof.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775986/connected-sum-of-surfaces-is-well-defined-proof-attempt https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121571/connected-sum-of-topological-manifolds/121635#121635

What have you tried? Lee's exercise gives a clear outline, at which step do you get stuck? Show your efforts.

I'm stuck on question a. I think I can answer the question using the classification theorem for compact surfaces but I especially don't want to use it (regarding that i need to proove that theorem right after).
For the question b and c, i think they are here to lead me to use Van Kampen theorem to prove that $\pi_1(M#N) = \pi _1(M) * \pi _1(N)$.
Is this correct or am I completely going in the wrong direction?
